# InvalidAccessKey when using configure-aws-credentials and jakejarvis/s3-sync-action (GitHub Actions)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, github-actions, amazon-iam, cicd

I am trying to integrate GitHub Actions *configure-aws-credentials* with *jakejarvis/s3-sync-action* and am getting the following error:

fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

This is the yaml:

```
name: Upload Website

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
    - main

permissions:
  id-token: write # This is required for requesting the JWT
  contents: read
  packages: write

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: configure aws credentials
      id: creds
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v3
      with:
        role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::(hidden intentionally from stack overflow)
        aws-region: 'us-east-1'
        output-credentials: true
    - name: show output creds
      run:  |
        echo steps.creds.outputs
    - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl private --follow-symlinks --delete
      env:
        AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ steps.creds.outputs.aws-access-key-id }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ steps.creds.outputs.aws-secret-access-key }}
        AWS_REGION: 'us-east-1'
        SOURCE_DIR: 'website'
```

These are a snippet of the results:
[image: part1]
[image: part2]

Any assistance is appreciated!

I am expecting to utilize the two GitHub Actions to sync with Amazon S3 in support of CI/CD. I am using the IAM Identity Center and AWS Organizations, thus cannot generate keys manually.

Comment: There is a problem in the action where the custom profile that is created so it only allows the access token / secret combination and thinks sts provided an invalid key.

I fixed it in [this pull request](https://github.com/jakejarvis/s3-sync-action/pull/86) but it looks like PRs haven't been pulled into that repo in a while.

I have a fork that works [https://github.com/kevin-reamer/s3-sync-action](https://github.com/kevin-reamer/s3-sync-action)